# how to debug network responce in react native

Tags: android, react-native

i am trying to debug my code in react native here i have a axios post request the only responce is i get when there is a error is axios error

rather than that i am looking to debug my code just like in react js by inspect element and network tab

currently i open my app using `npx react-native run-andoid` this opens the app in a emulator and is really diffcult to debug my code  can anyone suggest a better method for debugiing

```
   var Data56 = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        babyname: babyname,
        phone: nuber,
       
        baby_date: date,
      };
    }
   

    axios
      .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/register', Data56, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
      })

      .then(res => {
        props.navigation.navigate('Home_scrren', {data: Data56});
     
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ---> You can use Chrome Debugging and you need to add a breakpoint for it.

Comment: can u walk me through it

Comment: @AnkitVora i am using emulator how can i shake ?

Comment: ---> Within your app in the Android Emulator press Command + M on macOS or Ctrl + M on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @AnkitVora i got the following error when i clicked on debug

Comment: Not to worry ,you can simply reload the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250597/discussion-between-menu-cd-and-ankit-vora).

Answer (score 1):

Follow this Step:-

(1) First you need to shake the device and open the debug option, it will redirect you to chrome.

(2) You need to inspect that and open the console tab.

[image]

(3) You need to add breakpoints in VSCode or add breakpoints using chrome.

[image]

(4) then simply Reload the application, using that you can do step-by-step debugging.

Answer (score 1):

1][firstly you can see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5TS3hd9ktU)

2][exapmle with axios](https://codesandbox.io/s/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-gattu-patel-forked-u1zf4l?file=/src/App.js:1326-1363)

3] 2nd go to your console window and press D and see your emulator like this like this

[image]

- if you press d in console window and see your output in your emulator
  like this then then on the last option "Debug"
- it will navigate to chrome screen here is screenshot

[image]

- then write click on a screen and see option like inspect here is
  screenshot

[image]

- then then new screen will appear and go to consol tab there you can
  see your data like this

[image]

**I This this will help you**

Comment: i did a axios request this is not visible in network tab

Comment: I will post second answer please check here is class component  https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sun-5eg9ng?file=/src/App.js:0-1038

Answer (score 1):

```
if (__DEV__) {
  global.XMLHttpRequest = global.originalXMLHttpRequest
    ? global.originalXMLHttpRequest
    : global.XMLHttpRequest;
  global.FormData = global.originalFormData
    ? global.originalFormData
    : global.FormData;

  fetch; // Ensure to get the lazy property

  if (window.__FETCH_SUPPORT__) {
    // it's RNDebugger only to have
    window.__FETCH_SUPPORT__.blob = false;
  } else {
    /*
     * Set __FETCH_SUPPORT__ to false is just work for `fetch`.
     * If you're using another way you can just use the native Blob and remove the `else` statement
     */
    global.Blob = global.originalBlob ? global.originalBlob : global.Blob;
    global.FileReader = global.originalFileReader
      ? global.originalFileReader
      : global.FileReader;
  }
}
```

- add this code to root index.js
- turn on debug
- Check tab network like web,

we can see request and response,
one more option, you can add reactotron or flipper, this tool will log anything like network redux action..., without open debug mode
Hope this help you

Comment: where should i add this in index.js

Comment: just add above this line AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App); @menucd

Comment: can confirm this works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

I'm using axios and fetch data and you can see in chrome i will get all data in debug mood also I'm my step which one I post here

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { View, SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from "react-native";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const App = () => {
    
      const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getList()
      }, [])
    
      const getList = () => {
        axios({
          url: "https://fakestoreapi.com/users?limit=5",
        }).then((res) => {
          var response = res.data;
          console.log(response)
          setList(response)
        })
    
      }
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={list}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          }
        />
      )
    }
    export default App;
```

[image]