# React Native Debugger - how to inspect element in the debugger

Tags: javascript, react-native, debugging, mobile, react-native-debugger

In my React Native Debugger, I can't inspect element.
[image]

When I right click in React Native Debugger -> Toggle Element Inspector,
I can only toggle the element inspector in the emulator.

According to this video, I should be able to inspect the element in the Debugger
https://youtu.be/AbUs9nJuKNQ?t=117

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884776/how-to-debug-network-responce-in-react-native/74908891#74908891 see here hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was introduced in the new version of RN 0.71 - check this blog post: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/12/version-071#react-devtools

[image]

Comment: I want to inspect the DOM/styles as the Website inspector